# Naming convention for this/self within an evaluation context

Tags: oop, functional-programming, this, self, language-design

Let's take the following pseudo-syntax:

```
filter(
    $(this).rows.siblings, 
    $(this).Revenue > 100
)
```

What this means is that we want to get all `sibling` rows, and then keep only those where `Revenue > 100`.

However, the `this` is different for the two terms. For the first term, it means the `context` of the expression, and for the second term `this` means each member of the set produced by first term. Here would be an example:

```
Items = $(this).rows.siblings
==> [102, 100, 94]

filter(
    Items,
    $(this).Revenue > 99
)
==> [102, 100]
```

Is there a convention that can be used to better identify the `this` of the item? It's almost like the first `this` is the global `this` and the second `this` is the element in the loop expression. Perhaps something like `this` and `member`, or what might be a good naming convention here (without using `this` twice)?

Answer (score 1):

The receiver could be implied. The first argument to `filter` is a collection of elements. The second argument is the predicate. All functions calls with no explicitly defined received in the predicate are sent to an element of the collection:

```
filter(
    $(this).rows.siblings, 
    Revenue > 100
)
```

More commonly the programmer is expected to declare a lambda that takes an argument. In the example below, the letter `s` is a reference to an element in the collection.

```
filter(
    $(this).rows.siblings, 
    s -> s.Revenue > 100
)
```

Python list comprehension:

`[x for x in $(this).rows.siblings if x.Revenue > 100]`